# python authentication with requests library via POST

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests, forms-authentication

I read several similar topic.. I try to follow the others examples but I'm still stuck in the middle of nowhere..
I have basic skills of python programming and little knowledge about http protocol, my two goals are:
-succesfull authentication to a website via requests library
-fetch data from the website after the login while the session is active

This is the code:

```python
import requests

targetws = 'https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure'

s = requests.session()

payload_data = {'login_username': 'xxx', 'login_password': 'yyy'}

response = s.post(targetws, data=payload_data)


url='https://it.advfn.com/mercati/BIT/generali-G/ordini'

result = s.get(url) 

print result.content
```

But I always get no success with log in..
Maybe I miss some value in post data like submit action or else?
Any help will be appreciated, best regards!

Here the html code from the page:

```html
form action="https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure" id="login_form" name="login_form" method="POST" target="">

        <input type="hidden" value="aHR0cDovL2l0LmFkdmZuLmNvbQ==" name="redirect_url" id="redirect_url">
        <input type="hidden" value="it" name="site" id="site">

        <div class="fields"><label for="login_username">Username</label> 
            <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="text ui-widget-content" value =""
            id="login_username" name="login_username" maxlength="64">
        </div>

        <div class="fields"><label for="login_password">Password</label> 
            <input tabindex="2" type="password" class="text ui-widget-content" value="" id="login_password" name="login_password" maxlength="16">
        </div>
                <div class="fields">
                    <strong><a href="/common/account/password/request">Se ti sei dimenticato la tua password</a></strong> &nbsp;
                    <input  class="button"  tabindex="3" type="submit"   value="Accedi" id="login_submit">
                </div>
    </form
```

Comment: What is the response you get back when the login attempt fails? Check the `status_code` and `text` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, status code always 200 and text: 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deepbook.py", line 21, in <module>
    print result.text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 909: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: your connection type expecting header of form-url encoded and you are sending json object. data = 'username=' + user + '&password=' + password
        header = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        }

Comment: updated answer below..try it and accept if it worked or update your query on top of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what gets posted:

[image]

You see you need the `redirect_url` and `site` which you can parse from the input in the source with [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {"redirect_url": "",
        "site": "uk",
        "login_username": "foo",
        "login_password": "bar"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    log = "https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure"
    r = s.get("http://uk.advfn.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    redirect_url = soup.select_one("#redirect_url")["value"]
    site =  soup.select_one("#site")["value"]
    data["redirect_url"] = redirect_url
    p = s.post(log, data=data)
    print(p.content)
    print(s.get('https://it.advfn.com/mercati/BIT/generali-G/ordini').content)
```

Once you do that you will be successfully logged in.

Comment: The code that you write works! A big thanks for this help! Just few question to understand my mistake.. 1. When I use the s.post() the data are submitted over the header? 2. You said that when I call https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure I was redirected to http://uk.advfn.com/ but how you get that site? It's coded base64 in redirect_url? Should I check that variable (redirect_url) in the response message every time to be sure? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: 4. What kind of software do u use to catch the headers? cause with "live http header" extension for chrome I think that datas are sends via cookies after the first login.. Thanks!

Comment: INo prob, if you look at the source code, you can see under input tags the redirect_url and site, it is just a matter of parsing the values from the tags  to get what you need to post.  If you open chrome developer tools or firebug   you can see exactly what is happening under the network tab

Comment: Ok I alredy use firebug but I dindn't check the network tab. Just last question :) The page that s.get(page).content execute a javascript.. Could I execute it inside that requests library object or have to use something else like webkit?