# python requests: how to authenticate with post and access file over proxy

Tags: python, post, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to download a research article pdf via a university proxy into which I need to login. I tried following [this answer][1], but the resulting download contains only the login website.

- The article url might look like this: `https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aaf743/pdf`. (this one happens to be open access, but others need to be accessed this way).
- In the browser, I access this through a proxy: `https://login.emedien.ub.my-university.edu/login?qurl=https%3a%2f%2fiopscience.iop.org%2farticle%2f10.3847%2f2041-8213%2faaf743%2fpdf`. This url is stored in the variable `long_proxy` in the code sample below.
- In the browser, this brings up a login form:

  ```
  <form action="/login" method="post">
  <input name="ezproxycsrftoken" type="hidden" value="aBcDeFgH12345"/>
  <input name="url" type="hidden" value="https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aaf743/pdf">
  <table>
  <tr><td>University Username:</td><td><input name="user" style="width:250px" tabindex="1" type="text"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input name="pass" style="width:250px" tabindex="2" type="password"/></td></tr>
  </table>
  </input>
  </form>
  ```
- Upon entering the username/password, I get forwarded to

  https://iopscience-iop-org.emedien.ub.uni-muenchen.de/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aaf743/pdf

  which brings up the PDF in the browser. I call this url `short_proxy` in the code sample below.

I try to do that with python requests in the following way:

```
user_name = 'myname'
passwd = 'mypassword'

with requests.Session() as session:

    session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    # Parse the input form for the hidden input
    r2      = requests.get(long_proxy)
    soup    = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
    form    = soup.find('form')
    hidden  = form.find('input', attrs={'type':'hidden', 'name':'ezproxycsrftoken'}).attrs['value']
    url_res = form.find('input', attrs={'type':'hidden', 'name':'url'}).attrs['value']

    # set up the login

    payload = {
        'user': user_name,
        'pass': passwd,
        'ezproxycsrftoken': hidden,
        'url': url_res
    }

    # post login

    post = session.post(login, data=payload)

    # get data

    r3 = session.get(short_proxy)
    with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as fid:
        fid.write(r3.content)
```

- However the downloaded file is not actually a PDF, but turns out to be the html code of the login page.

Any ideas how to get the PDF?

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816565/python-authentication-with-requests-library-via-post
```

Comment: What's your login variable set to?
Also, based on that you're being redirected to the login page, the login post might not be working. You should try printing the response of that to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `requests.Session()` in order to save cookies/session that the website gives you, yet you're using `requests.get()` instead of `session.get()` for your initial request where you fetch your `longproxy`. 
Changing your

```
r2      = requests.get(long_proxy)
```

to

```
r2      = session.get(long_proxy)
```

Should fix your issue. I can not verify this however.
Also note that your long_proxy

```
https://login.emedien.ub.uni-muenchen.de/login?qurl=https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aaf743/
```

is simply the login url, followed by the pdf url. So you don't really have to fetch that.
 This could save you some extra requests / execution time